# How can I remove Alert prompts programmatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

On a button click, I start a process that takes sometime and once it gets finished I navigate to a specified screen.

While under process, I [`Alert`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html) a "*loading*" prompt which according to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html): "*By default, the only button will be an 'OK' button"*. And once the process is done, I alert again that the data is ready.

Problem is that I get two prompts above each other, and that they need user's click to be removed.

I would like to remove the first prompt before displaying the second (and maybe set a timer for the second to then remove it as well).

How can I remove `Alert` prompts programmatically?

Comment: You can use custom modal to achieve this instead of using Alert.

Comment: @digit I don't want to cover the whole screen with a prompt message, and then to "click" it for it to disappear. I would like something similar to a toast in `Android`.

Comment: Then you can use ToastAndroid -> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toastandroid.html .

Comment: @digit this works on IOS too?

Comment: currently there is no way, i had to fork my own react-native repo and create a dismiss method to be able to get them to go away. i only did it for iOS since that's the platform I'm developing on, but i plan on PRing to facebook/react-native and hopefully they'll add it into the next version.

Comment: Does it have to be an alert? You can always create a separate component to work as your custom alert. Position it absolutely, center it, and change its inner text programmatically using props

Comment: @Raymond can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic workaround in order to achieve what you're asking for would be to create a separate component that will act as the alert instead.

The component that I've written accepts two props. `text` and `visible`.

Inside your screen you can add it as so:

```
import React from 'react'
[....]

export default class Screen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: true,
    text: "Loading... Please wait"
  }

  drawAlert() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({text: "Will dismiss in 1 second"}, () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({visible: false})
        }, 1000);
      })
    }, 4000); // fake API request
    return (
      <Alert text={this.state.text} visible={this.state.visible} />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Alert text={this.state.text} visible={this.state.visible} />
    )
  }
}
```

This is the `alert` component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native'

export default class Alert extends Component {
  state = {
    text: this.props.text,
    visible: this.props.visible
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({text: nextProps.text, visible: nextProps.visible})
  }

  drawBox() {
    if (this.state.visible) {
      return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.boxContainer}>
            <View style={styles.textContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.text}</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress} style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>OK</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.drawBox()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    zIndex: 99999,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  boxContainer: {
      backgroundColor: "#FFF",
      borderRadius: 2,
      padding: 10,
      width: 300,
      borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
      elevation: 1,
      padding: 20
  },
  textContainer: {
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  text: {
    color: "#424242",
    fontFamily: "Roboto",
    fontSize: 18
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    alignItems: 'flex-start'
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "#009688"
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.