# How to cancel AlertIOS programmatically

Tags: javascript, react-native

### Description

I have a component with Barcode scanner. After the barcode scanner returns a value, the AlertIOS with a prompt shows up, with **Cancel** and **Save** buttons. Now one option is to click **Save** button for sending the value to the server. For the other option, the client wishes to send data with volume down button or cancel with volume up button.

### Problem

Now I already have set up confirmation with volume down button, but I would also like to close the Alert popup when pressing any of the buttons.

### My code

For alert:

```
showAlert(value) {
     this.alert = AlertIOS.prompt(
        `Gescannter Wert: ${value}`,
        'Menge eingeben (Standartwert ist 1)',
        [{
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () => this.scanning = true,
            style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
            text: 'Save',
            onPress: (input) => this.pushCodeData(value, input)
        }],
        'plain-text',
        '1',
        'number-pad',
    );
}
```

for volume change detection:

```
        this.volumeListener = SystemSetting.addVolumeListener((data) => {
        let volume = data.value.toFixed(1);
        console.log(volume, this.VOLUME);
        SystemSetting.setVolume(this.VOLUME);

        if (volume < this.VOLUME && this.scanning === false) {
            console.log("confirm")
            this.pushCodeData(this.state.scannedValue, 1)

        } else if (volume > this.VOLUME && this.scanning === false){
            console.log("cancel")
            this.scanning = true
        }
    });
```

The function that sends the data is `this.pushCodeData(params...)`

Is it even possible to programmatically close the alert prompt? So far I couldn't find any answers to this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to close an alert programmatically yet. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4928

You may give it a try.

[How can I remove Alert prompts programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708944/how-can-i-remove-alert-prompts-programmatically)